# Strange Xcode Code Glitch

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

So I'm getting these 3 random errors all of a sudden. I have rebooted and cleaned the project. Has anyone run into this strange bug where the compiler doesn't see classes and protocols that are clearly included in the project. To be clear this code was working fine until and now it's not.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you have a problem in SWPlayer.h

Comment: Also, make sure you delete `DerivedData`

Comment: Can you check if `SWPlayer.m` is linked to your target ?

Comment: I've check the links and delete the DerivedData. Still nothing. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

(1) You aren't importing the header file that is defining those types.

(2) The header file that is supposed to define those types is hosed.

Check `SWPlayer.h` to see if you have a misplaced `#if...` or unclosed comments or something.